# $modx->getObject returns NULL

Tags: php, code-snippets, modx, modx-evolution, modx-resources

I've got a problem with modx evo (1.0.15). I wanna get resource by id in my snippet. Snippet call looks like this:

```
[[byid? &id=`3`]]
```

and proccessing looks like this:

```
$name = 'modResource';
$criteria = array('id' => $id);
$document = $modx->getObject($name,$criteria);
print_r (var_dump($docArray));
```

I tried this

```
$resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $id);
```

and this

```
$resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', 3);
```

all these variants gave me NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1.0.15 is evolution version, not revolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.0.15 is modx evolution. You need to call like following.

```
$resource = $modx->getDocumentObject('id',3);
```

You can get more information in evolution specific docs.
http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/API:getDocumentObject